# Download all images by their URL in React JS to Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download, client

I am looking for a way to download multiple images in a given array, filled with image URLs, by clicking a download button.

So far I am able to download a single image.

```
class Images extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            imageUrl: "",
            imageArray: [
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578895210405-907db486c111?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=661&q=80,
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572166365087-96ac83103260?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80,
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508706000025-b720ee541485?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1410&q=80],

        }
    }

    fileDownloadHandler = async (pictureUrl) => {
        console.log(pictureUrl)
        const response = await fetch(pictureUrl);
        response.blob().then(blob => {
            let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'picture.jpeg';
            a.click();
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <button type='button' onClick={()=>this.fileDownloadHandler(this.state.imageArray[0])}>Download Pictures</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the fileDownloadHandler to take the whole array and then iterate over the images on the click.

```
class Images extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        imageUrl: "",
        imageArray: [
```

`https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578895210405-907db486c111?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=661&q=80,
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572166365087-96ac83103260?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80,
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508706000025-b720ee541485?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1410&q=80],`

```
    }
}

fileDownloadHandler = async (pictures) => {
    for (var i = 0; i< pictures.length; i++) {
    console.log(pictureUrl)
    const response = await fetch(pictures[i]);
    response.blob().then(blob => {
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'picture.jpeg';
        a.click();
    });
  }
}

render() {
    return (
            <button type='button' onClick={()=>this.fileDownloadHandler(this.state.imageArray)}>Download Pictures</button>
```

Comment: This is not really a good solution. It opens the download window for every iteration.